# Problem with getting a hidden value in JS when there are multiple records in table (Coldfusion)

Tags: javascript, database, coldfusion

This is my table where I have this column that lets the user choose a predicted time.

```
<cfoutput query="getReservations">
       <tbody>
        <td><input class="form-control predicted" name="predicted" id="ReservaTempoPrevisto" placeholder="HH:MM" value="#timeFormat(ReservaTempoPrevisto,'HH:mm')#">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" class="id" value="#ReservaID#"></td>
```

Then I have the JS code (that tries to get the time the user chose and the id of that record):

```
//Update the predicted time
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $(".predicted").on("change",function(event){
                var hora = this.value;
                console.log("Updating time = "+ hora);
                var id = jQuery('input[type=hidden][name=id]').val();
                console.log(id);
                $.ajax({
                        url: "horaPrevista-update-database.cfc"
                        , type: "POST"
                        , dataType: "json"
                        , data: {"method" : "updatePredicted", "returnFormat": "json", "hora": hora, "id": id}
                    }).done(function(response) {
                        console.log("response", response);
                    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                       console.log("errorMessage",errorMessage);
                    });
          });
        });
```

And the horaPrevista-update-database.cfc component:

```
<cfcomponent>   
<cfset variables.dsn = "listareservas">

<cffunction name="updatePredicted" returntype="struct" access="remote">
   <cfargument name="hora" type="string" required="true">
   <cfargument name="id" type="numeric" required="true">

   <cfset local.response = {success=true}>

   <cftry>
       <cfquery datasource="#variables.dsn#">
           UPDATE Reservas
           SET    ReservaTempoPrevisto = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#arguments.hora#"> 
           WHERE  ReservaID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.id#">
       </cfquery>
       <cfcatch>    
           <!--- add handling here... --->
           <cfset local.response = {success=false}>
       </cfcatch>
   </cftry>

   <cfreturn local.response>
</cffunction>
```

The problem is when I have multiple records on the table, it always updates the first record, because the hidden field id that the JS gets is always the id of the first record. What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: Nothing to do with the issue, but don't use the same id value for all of the time text boxes. Per spec, the DOM "id" values should be unique within the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using a unique ID on the hidden element so the JS will not know which one you mean when you select it when there are multiple of them, it will just use the first element it sees.

In this instance it will be easier to use data attributes to provide the information rather then a hidden field.

```
<input class="form-control predicted" name="predicted" id="ReservaTempoPrevisto" placeholder="HH:MM" value="#timeFormat(ReservaTempoPrevisto,'HH:mm')#" data-id="#ReservaID#">
```

Then you can do:

```
var hora = this.value;
console.log("Updating time = "+ hora);
var id = $(this).data('id');
console.log(id);
```